# google maps warning about non existing addDomListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is all what I have as javascript code on a page:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=... some code" width="100%" height="500" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

so there is no addDomListener or addEventListener() or any additional code anywhere

but in console I'm getting this warning:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead
```

how to avoid this warning ?

Comment: It's not your code so why worry about it? Raise an issue with Google Maps if it really bothers you

Comment: isn't the path something like `/maps/embed/v1/*map_mode*` ? and there's no `pb` parameter described in any documentation I've seen

Comment: @JaromandaX - this code is from google maps page. Find a desired location - click on `share` - `embed` - `copy html` button

Comment: @Phil - who sends this warning in console - browser or google ?

Comment: The warning is coming from Google's own code.

Comment: @Phil - so do you believe that Google developers writes `addDomListener()` instead of `addEventListener()` and then send the warning to themselves ?

Comment: It's simple deduction. You said _"this is all what I have as javascript code on a page"_. It's unlikely there's any GMaps code in `polyfill.js` (though you didn't provide a stack trace so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯) so the bad function call _must_ be coming from the GMaps embedded iFrame.

Comment: @Phil - I remove entire `polyfill` script - the map works - the warning is still there. Iframe code is `copy/paste`  from google maps - `embed` option

Comment: oh, fair enough - I thought it was from the maps API as for `send the warning to themselves` - no the warning is in your browser, it's not sent to google (though if you use Chrome, I bet it is)

Comment: Oh, and yes, it's googles own code that is using `addDomListener` - clearly the code boffins at google don't talk to each other, so those working on one part don't know that the functions have been deprecated ... no surprises there, most google coders couldn't write hello world without help

Comment: @JaromandaX - is there a way to contact them ? Those responsible for this issue. And I would be very happy to quote your words

Comment: I'm sure google knows about it already

Comment: @JaromandaX - and what is then the reason to keep the issue ? They write a wrong code - they know that they write a wrong code - and they keep the wrong code. Strange.

Comment: @provance - you misunderstand ... google knows because they've indexed this question :p the coders still have no idea, but google knows :p don't know where you'd report this non-issue though